# Как задать имя ключа для связи многие ко многим?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Для разработки базы данных использую подход *code first*. Есть два класса

```
public class Assembly
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<OperationItem> Items {get;set;} = new List<OperationItem>();
}

public class OperationItem
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Assembly> Assemblies {get;set;} = new List<Assembly>();
}
```

на основании этого entity framework генерирует следующую миграцию:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.AssemblyOperationItems",
    c => new
        {
            Assembly_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
            OperationItem_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Assembly_Id, t.OperationItem_Id })
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Assemblies", t => t.Assembly_Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.OperationItems", t => t.OperationItem_Id)
    .Index(t => t.Assembly_Id)
    .Index(t => t.OperationItem_Id);
```

сам скрипт миграции корректный, меня не устраивает присваиваемые имена: `Assembly_Id & OperationItem_Id`, а в во всех остальных таблицах ключи называются `AssemblyId & OperationItemId`.

Можно ли сказать EF что бы он генерировал имена без использования `_` в имени ключа при создании связи многие ко многим.

P.S. Я знаю про то что данную проблему можно решить если создать связь через `fluent api`, интересует иное решение, атрибуты аннотации и т.п.

Comment: класс должен называться Assembly, а не AssemblyId, верно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда используется связь many-to-many, то используется соглашение об именовании FK, которые перегрузить не имеется возможности с помощью аннотации. Согласно соглашению об именовании, FK формируется по следующему правилу

> <имя таблицы>_<имя первичного ключа таблицы>

То, что мы и наблюдаем в примере.

Чтобы это перегрузить, можно сделать следующее:

1. Как вы отметили, **использовать FluentAPI** следующим образом:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Assembly>()
          .HasMany<OperationItem>(s => s.Items)
          .WithMany(c => c.Assemblies)
          .Map(cs =>
          {
              cs.MapLeftKey("ItemsRefId");
              cs.MapRightKey("AssembliesRefId");

          });
    }
   ```

   В результате, у нас получится следующая миграция:

   ```
   CreateTable(
               "dbo.AssemblyOperationItems",
               c => new
                   {
                       ItemsRefId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                       AssembliesRefId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                   })
               .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ItemsRefId, t.AssembliesRefId })
               .ForeignKey("dbo.Assemblies", t => t.ItemsRefId, cascadeDelete: true)
               .ForeignKey("dbo.OperationItems", t => t.AssembliesRefId, cascadeDelete: true)
               .Index(t => t.ItemsRefId)
               .Index(t => t.AssembliesRefId);
   ```
2. **Перегрузить соглашение по именованию вторичных ключей**.

Когда нас не устраивает стандартное соглашение имен, мы можем это соглашение перегрузить. Пример взять [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469439?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Определим класс по переименованию имен для вторичных ключей, который будет удалять символ _, который генерируется согласно стандартному соглашению имен.

```
// Provides a convention for fixing the independent association (IA) foreign key column names.  
    public class ForeignKeyNamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
    {

        public void Apply(AssociationType association, DbModel model)
        {
            // Identify ForeignKey properties (including IAs)  
            if (association.IsForeignKey)
            {
                // rename FK columns  
                var constraint = association.Constraint;
                if (DoPropertiesHaveDefaultNames(constraint.FromProperties, constraint.ToRole.Name, constraint.ToProperties))
                {
                    NormalizeForeignKeyProperties(constraint.FromProperties);
                }
                if (DoPropertiesHaveDefaultNames(constraint.ToProperties, constraint.FromRole.Name, constraint.FromProperties))
                {
                    NormalizeForeignKeyProperties(constraint.ToProperties);
                }
            }
        }

        private bool DoPropertiesHaveDefaultNames(ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmProperty> properties, string roleName, ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmProperty> otherEndProperties)
        {
            if (properties.Count != otherEndProperties.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (!properties[i].Name.EndsWith("_" + otherEndProperties[i].Name))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void NormalizeForeignKeyProperties(ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmProperty> properties)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; ++i)
            {
                int underscoreIndex = properties[i].Name.IndexOf('_');
                if (underscoreIndex > 0)
                {
                    properties[i].Name = properties[i].Name.Remove(underscoreIndex, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Включаем класс перегрузке именования вторичных ключей в нашу модель следующим образом

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            /*modelBuilder.Entity<Assembly>()
                .HasMany<OperationItem>(s => s.Items)
                .WithMany(c => c.Assemblies)
                .Map(cs =>
                {
                    cs.MapLeftKey("ItemsRefId");
                    cs.MapRightKey("AssembliesRefId");

                });
                */

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ForeignKeyNamingConvention>();
        }
```

В результате, мы получаем следующую миграцию

```
        CreateTable(
                "dbo.OperationItemAssemblies",
                c => new
                    {
                        OperationItemId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        AssemblyId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.OperationItemId, t.AssemblyId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.OperationItems", t => t.OperationItemId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Assemblies", t => t.AssemblyId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.OperationItemId, name: "IX_OperationItem_Id")
                .Index(t => t.AssemblyId, name: "IX_Assembly_Id");
```

Как вы могли заметить, имена вторичных ключей теперь стали без символа '**_**'.